# CSS/Bootstrap/HTML issues sizing image and code improvements?

Tags: css, image, bootstrap-4

I'm fairly new to CSS/Bootstrap and could use some help from professionals. 
My problem is that I can't get an image to fit the exact dimensions of a div, it gets all distorted if I set the actual IMG tag height and width, basically I want a nice thumbnail. The goal is for users to upload so images will be all different sizes Landscape/ portrait. If you see the image I attached I like how my windows mail crops out the images to fit in a "div" and zoom in on the center or something. See image. https://publicadamwebgis.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Capture2.JPG
This is also for a mobile view approx 375px.
Please see the jsfiddlle code. The JSFiddle here does not really work well. The link works better.

https://jsfiddle.net/dfmrjqs1/

```css
    .RestrauantMainLi{
    border: 1px solid rgb(155, 155, 155);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    height: 140px;
    transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    }

    .RestrauantLiIcons{       
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .progress {
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 height: 0.5rem;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-size: .75rem;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: .25rem;
 margin-top: 6px;
 width:inherit;
 padding-left: 2px;
 padding-right: 2px;
 }

 .progressbar1 {
 color:hotpink;
 border-radius: 5px;
 }

 .percentbox{
 float:left;
 height: 25px;
 width: 18%;
 background-color:#a9b1b1;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-top: 2px;
 font-size: 10pt;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 }
 .statusbox{
 height: 25px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width: auto;
 padding-top: 3px;
 }

    .RestrauantMainListyle2{
    height: inherit;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .RestrauantMainThumbnailContainer{
    height:inherit;
    width:160px;
    }

    .RestrauantMainThumbnail{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3590d6dbc0.js"></script>



<body>
<div class = 'container RestrauantMainLi'>
    <div class ='row' style = 'height: inherit;'>
        <div class = 'col-7 RestrauantMainListyle2'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class = 'col-10'>
                    Jets Pizza 
                </div>
                <div class = 'col-2'>
                    <i class='fas fa-info-circle'></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class = 'col-6'>Chines</div>
                <div class = 'col-6'>$$</div>
            </div>
            <div class= 'RestrauantLiIcons'>
                <i class='far fa-thumbs-up'>34</i>
                <i class='far fa-thumbs-down'>23</i>
                <i class='far fa-comments'>23</i>
                <i class='fas fa-route'></i>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class='container percentbox'>5</div>
                <div class='container statusbox'>
                    <div class='container progress'>
                    <div class='progress-bar bg-success progressbar1' style='width:80%'></div>
                    <div class='progress-bar bg-danger progressbar1' style='width:50%'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class ='row' style = 'justify-content: center' >
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = 'col-5 RestrauantMainThumbnailContainer'>
            <img src = 'https://publicadamwebgis.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/IMG_9249.jpg'class="img-thumbnail RestrauantMainThumbnail">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Also I don't even know if my CSS code or html is done correctly. Any help to improve my code or address any issues, would be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is your desire output. I modify the `img.RestrauantMainThumbnail` CSS. I added `img` is to specify a higher CSS selector specificity to override the class `img-thumbnail` from bootstrap-4 for the `height` property.

```
img.RestrauantMainThumbnail {
  /* change from max-width to width */
  width: 100%;
  /* change from max-height to height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Add object-fit to specify how the contents of a replaced element should be fitted to the box */
  object-fit: fill; /* values: contain / cover / ... */
}
```

```css
.RestrauantMainLi {
  border: 1px solid rgb(155, 155, 155);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  height: 140px;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.RestrauantLiIcons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.progress {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 0.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: .75rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: inherit;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.progressbar1 {
  color: hotpink;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.percentbox {
  float: left;
  height: 25px;
  width: 18%;
  background-color: #a9b1b1;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.statusbox {
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.RestrauantMainListyle2 {
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.RestrauantMainThumbnailContainer {
  height: inherit;
}

img.RestrauantMainThumbnail {
  /* change from max-width to width */
  width: 100%;
  /* change from max-height to height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Add object-fit to specify how the contents of a replaced element should be fitted to the box */
  object-fit: fill; /* values: contain / cover / ... */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3590d6dbc0.js"></script>

<div class='container RestrauantMainLi'>
  <div class='row' style='height: inherit;'>
    <div class='col-7 RestrauantMainListyle2'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-10'>
          Jets Pizza
        </div>
        <div class='col-2'>
          <i class='fas fa-info-circle'></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-6'>Chines</div>
        <div class='col-6'>$$</div>
      </div>
      <div class='RestrauantLiIcons'>
        <i class='far fa-thumbs-up'>34</i>
        <i class='far fa-thumbs-down'>23</i>
        <i class='far fa-comments'>23</i>
        <i class='fas fa-route'></i>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class='container percentbox'>5</div>
        <div class='container statusbox'>
          <div class='container progress'>
            <div class='progress-bar bg-success progressbar1' style='width:80%'></div>
            <div class='progress-bar bg-danger progressbar1' style='width:50%'></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row' style='justify-content: center'>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-5 RestrauantMainThumbnailContainer' style="border: thin solid orange">
      <img src='https://publicadamwebgis.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/IMG_9249.jpg' class="img-thumbnail RestrauantMainThumbnail">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: NIce man this worked for me . I see the  object-fit: fill property is the one I was looking for. Thanks a lot!